# Can't access .env file from python

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, secret-key

I have django `settings.py` file and `.env` in same folder. `.env` file:

```
DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY=123456678910
```

In settings.py i call theese variables as `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')`. Django says me
 
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you doing to actually use the .env file? How are you starting your app?

Comment: @DanielRoseman simply by `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.env files aren't a feature of Django, Python, or virtualenv. If you want to use them, you'll need to start your app with something that knows about them.

One way of doing this is to install Foreman, create a Procfile, and run it via `foreman start ...`. If you're planning to deploy to Heroku, use `heroku local`.

Comment: thanks for answer, but what if I don't want to use third-party libs?

Comment: Then don't use `.env` files. Set the environment variables manually, or (eg) in your .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set this code in your `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` files respectively.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project_name.settings.local")
```

I have found this solution from Daniel Greenfield's book `Two scoops of Django.` Hope this will solve your issue.

Thanks.